# output is returning NaN how do i get ride of the NaN without dropping the whole row

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

i am trying to combine columns from excel sets and when i combine the columns it places a NaN were the column is empty. how do i get rid of the NaN without dropping the whole row?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
  qw = pd.read_excel(f)
  df = df.append(qw)
  cf = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.contains('address1|address2|city|state|zip|Location Address', case=False)]
  vf = df['address1'].map(str) + '-' + df['address2'].map(str) + '-' + df['city'].map(str) + '-' + df['state'].map(str) + '-' + df['zip'].map(str)
export_csv = vf.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: Pandas `fillna()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `replace` function

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
    qw = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(qw)
    cf = df.iloc[:, 
    df.columns.str.contains('address1|address2|city|state|zip|Location Address', case=False)]
    vf = df['address1'].map(str) + '-' + df['address2'].map(str) + '-' + 
    df['city'].map(str) + '-' + df['state'].map(str) + '-' + df['zip'].map(str)
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
export_csv = vf.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: `df[pd.isnull(df)] = ""` or `.fillna()` is another option that does the same thing

Comment: if it's works can you like and approve the solution

Comment: i approved the solution

Comment: i am having another problem with the code. do you mind helping because i have tired many ways to solve it?

Comment: sure I am happy to help you

Comment: ok thank you can i email you because stackflow is not letting me start a chat with you.

Comment: i posted the second question